# Dell XPS 9560 17.10 -> 19.04?

Tags: dell, 17.10, 19.04

I have a dell XPS 9560 and running 17.10 without major problems. (Minor hibernate/wake up problems, high battery usage, but nothing super critical)

When I tried to upgrade to 18.04 it all went down the drain: Could not properly shutdown (would crash, reason unknown) or boot into desktop (nvidia driver problem, but I didn't know at that time).

But I thought about upgrading to 19.04 and to save some time I thought about asking here first:

- Has anyone experience with 9560 and 19.04? I've read a reddit post, mentioning 9570 and working ok, so I guess 9560 should be ok as well?
- Can I upgrade from 17.10 directly to 19.04? What is the best approach for this?

I hope this post is not to open ended.

Comment: 17.10 went end of life a while ago so questions on that are no longer accepted. My method would be to re-install 19.04. Make a backup of personal data (well, you already should have those) and restore a backup after installing

Comment: Yeah, upgrading that far is not a good idea, I had problems upgrading from 18.04 to 19.04, so you will almost certainly have problems going that far.

Comment: I came across this page that might provide some insight into your question. [AskUbuntu - Question from 4 months ago](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1130947/should-i-do-a-direct-upgrade-from-16-04-to-19-04)

Comment: After reading the linked post from @CrashFive I have one question: Is a backup of /home enough? It is on a different partition, so theoretically be save during a clean installation - right?

Comment: morpheus05: You can upgrade in two steps, as detailed in the second and third sections of [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1166905/22949) to [How can I upgrade from 17.04 to the latest non-LTS Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1166299/22949). @warsong Going from 18.04 to 19.04 is *supposed* to work, as [they're supported releases and the one in between is EOL](https://askubuntu.com/q/719465/22949). It worked for me both times I tested it, though one of the times I had trouble in the *preceding* upgrade from 17.10 to 18.04 (but that was simple to fix, see the first linked post if interested).